# Spring data jpa save does not work. What am I missing?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, netbeans, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity BaseEntity, an entity Account, an AccountRepository, a bean calling the save-method of the repository and an arquillian-test. 
Running the test does not work and I do not know why. Maybe someone can tell me what I am missing.

```
    @EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
    @MappedSuperclass
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updated;
    private String entityname;

    public BaseEntity() {
    this.created = new Date();
    this.updated = this.created;
    this.entityname = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void update() {
       this.updated = new Date();
    }
    }
```

```
    @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    public class Account extends BaseEntity {

    @Embedded
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private Address address;
    @Column(length = 20)
    @Size(min = 6, max = 20)
    @NotNull
    private String telephone;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Email
    @NotNull
    private String email;
    @Column(length = 40)
    @NotNull
    private String passhash;
    @Column(length = 5)
    @NotNull
    private Language preferredLanguage;
    @Column(length = 32)
    private String passwordResetKey;
    @Column(length = 32)
    private String emailConfirmationKey;
    @NotNull
    private AccountStatus status;
```

```
    @Transactional 
    @Repository
    public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long>, 
    CrudRepository<Account, Long> {

    Account findByEmail(String email);
    }
```

```
    @Transactional
    public class RegistrationBean {

    @Inject
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public Account register(Account _account) {
    System.out.println("Id before saving: " + _account.getId());
    Account account = this.accountRepository.save(_account); 

    System.out.println("Id after saving: " + account.getId());
    System.out.println("How many accounts are there after saving? : " + 
    this.accountRepository.count());

    return account;
    }
```

```
    @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
    public class RegistrationTest {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addPackages(true, "net.company")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/beans.xml", "WEB-INF/beans.xml")
            .addAsResource("persistence-test.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
    System.out.println(archive.toString(true));
    return archive;
    }
    @Inject
    private RegistrationBean registrationBean;

    @Test
    public void testRegisterAndLoadPerson() {
    Person person = giveMeAValidPerson();
    System.out.println("************ 1 Person: " + person.toString());

    person = (Person) this.registrationBean.register(person);
    System.out.println("************ 2 Person: " + person.toString());
    Account loadedPerson = 
    (this.registrationBean.getAccountByEmail(person.getEmail()));
    System.out.println("*************loadedPerson: " + loadedPerson.toString());

    }
    }
```

Under META-INF I have application.properties, beans.xml and persistence.xml
application.properties:

```
    #Database Configuration
    db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/testApp
    db.username=testApp

    db.password=testApp
```

beans.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
    <jpa:repositories base-package="net.company.app.repositories" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" 
    ignore-resource-not-found="false"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>
    </beans:beans>
```

persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns
    /persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="net.company_OurAppPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>net.wakeit.agency.entities.Account</class>
    <class>net.wakeit.agency.entities.Person</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost
    /testAgency"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="testApp"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="testApp"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" 
    value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" 
    value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

The Id always stays null and findAll does not give any Accounts after saving. :-
I do not see, what I am missing.
Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Your annotations for transactions are useless. You have `@Transactional` but not a `<tx:annotation-driven />` to enable transactions, next to that you need a transaction manager. Also do you use Spring or CDI? beans.xml is the trigger to enable CDI and not spring, so I suggest renaming the beans.xml. In your spring configuration there is also no `EntityManagerFactory` defined nor looked up from JNDI. So I'm not sure what you are trying but it looks like you want Spring but have CDI and expect those to work automatically together.

Comment: The AccountRepository interface should have no annotations at all